# how to zip the file without compression

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

i create expansion file with the help of following link http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

but i am not sure how to create zip file without compression.

what exe do we use to zip the file without compression.. when i try the command zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files, i am getting below error.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>zip
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

some one please help me.

Comment: Did you see the part that says: "Each file can be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose, but we recommend you use a **compressed** file to conserve bandwidth during the download"

Answer (score 3):

May this Help you..

Check the `java.util.zip` class, it provides both zip & gzip functionality for compression and decompression.

**Edit:**

Another Option to do that is:

Assuming you are using `Microsoft Windows and WinZip` you can create an archive without compression by setting the Compression option to None.

1. Run WinZip (All Programs-->WinZip-->WinZip...)
2. On the WinZip Window click on the 'New' button on the button bar or select File-->New
3. Decide on a file name and directory where to save the archive
4. On the Add Window look for the 'Compression' option (just below action) and select None from the drop down list. You can also try the Super Fast option.

Comment: mate how can we run this command zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files .. any external tool?